# Load font locally via CSS

Tags: css, font-face

I have a small static website and I need to move it on an USB to make it possible to open it via this USB.

Via CSS I defined those rules for the fonts (Is a custom font):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SerifReg';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SansBol';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansBol.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansBol.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansBol.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansBol.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SansLig';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansLig.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansLig.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansLig.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansLig.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SansDem';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansDem.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansDem.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansDem.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
  src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSansDem.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

body {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SansLig';
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SerifReg';
  font-size: 40px !important;
}

h4 {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SansBol';
  line-height:1.5em;
}

p {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SansLig';
  font-size:16px;
}

b {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SerifReg';
  font-size:18px;
}
```

And I have no problem to load the fonts while visiting the website via We

**EDIT:**

A screen from the Console, Looks like the "fonts" folder is not loaded in "Sources"

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxdTr.png)

The problem appears only when I try to load the website in Local: the font's are not loaded.

What am I writing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Maybe there is an issue finding the file? Right click, select 'inspect element' and then click the console tab. There may be an error regarding the file location.

Comment: @ReeceKenney Hi, already tired and No errors in console :/

Comment: Can you tell how are you using that font in your stylesheet?

Comment: _"to make it possible to visit it locally"_ - and that means what, exactly? Did you set up a local web server? If not, and you are just viewing this via the local file system, then you most certainly do not want to use URLs that start with a `/`

Comment: @ReeceKenney I edited the post and locally looks like the "font" folder is not loaded in the Sources...

Comment: If you go to the font file in your browser, does it find the file? For example, in your address bar, go to: http://localhost/yourSite//assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.ttf

Answer (score 1):

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont_SerifReg';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Please make sure to cross-check below trouble shooting guide:

1. path provided in **url()**
2. Apply Style as below for example:
   body{
   font-family: 'MyFont_SerifReg';  // Same name defined in rule
   }
3. Add reference of your CSS file where rules are defined in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the path problem.
Try to use relative path (assume the assets folder is at the same place as the html): ../assets/fonts/MyFontSerifReg.ttf

Comment: Hi, also tried like this and nothing... always same problem

Comment: Put font file the same place with the html, and use local to load it:@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont_SerifReg';
  src: local ('MyFontSerifReg.ttf') format('truetype');